# Modularization of PL/SQL packages

Tags: plsql

Currently I am doing a restructuring project mainly on the Oracle PL/SQL packages in our company. It involves working on many of the core packages of our company. We never had documentation for the back end work done so far and the intention of this project is to create a new set of APIs based on the current logic in a structured way along with avoiding all unwanted logic that currently exists in the system.

We are also making a new module currently for the main business of the organization that would work based on these newly created back-end APIs.

As I started of this project, I found out that most of the wrapper APIs had around more than 8000 lines of code. I managed to covert this code into many single APIs and invoked them from the wrapper API.

This activity in itself has been a time-consuming process but I was able to cut down the number of lines of code to just 900 in the wrapper API by calling independent APIs for each business functionality.

I would like to know from you experts if this mode of modularizing the code is good and worth the time invested in it as I am not sure if it would have many performance benefits.
But from a code readability perspective, this is definitely helping and now I am able to understand the 8000 lines of code much better after restructuring and I am sure the other developers in my organization too will understand.

Requesting you to let me know if I am doing the right thing and if its having its advantages apart from readability please do mention them. Sorry for the long explanation.
And is it okay having more than 1000 lines of code in a wrapper API.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "wrapper API". A package, a package body, an individual procedure within a package?

Comment: Hi david, sorry that i didn't mention . its a procedure inside a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Easy to debug
- Easy to update
- Easy to Modify/maintain
- Less change proneness due to low coupling.
- Increases reuse if the modules are made generic
- Can identify unused code easily

Comment: Thanks a lot realspirituals ..i agree 100% with these points as now i clearly understand that these points were missing when i started working in this procedure. since i have divided it into many independent api's i hope the above points will prove useful for future developments and maintenance.

Comment: @njnbat If you are satisfied with answer, you can upvote and/or accept the answer, which would be more polite

Comment: tried but no reputation , so sorry for not being polite.